# The function np.linalg.inv() doesn't work correctly

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I actually work on some matrices and when I inverse it, the inverse is wrong. I use np.linalg.inv() to inverse my square matrix.

My example his:

```
import numpy as np
M = np.array([[9.0, 5.329070518200756e-17, -7.199999999999999, -5.3999999999999995, 0.0, 0.0], [5.329070518200756e-17, 9.0, 5.3999999999999995, -7.199999999999999, 0.0, 0.0], [-7.199999999999999, 5.3999999999999995, 11.422222222222222, 1.6653345369377363e-17, -2.4222222222222225, -7.266666666666667], [-5.3999999999999995, -7.199999999999999, 1.6653345369377363e-17, 11.422222222222222, 7.266666666666667, -2.4222222222222225], [0.0, 0.0, -2.4222222222222225, 7.266666666666667, 24.22222222222222, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, -7.266666666666667, -2.4222222222222225, 0.0, 24.22222222222222]])
M_inv = np.linalg.inv(M)
# It's not the Identity! 
print( M_inv @ M)
```

Do you have clues ?
Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188979/is-numpy-linalg-inv-giving-the-correct-matrix-inverse-edit-why-does-inv-gi) may help

Comment: You have a rather large condition numer.

Comment: You don't show the print.  This is a floating calculation, so don't expect exact 1/0 values.

Comment: I dont expect the 1/0 values, but i got like none sens numbers .

Comment: try using np.pinv()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [numpy.linalg.inv](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.inv.html?highlight=linalg%20inv#numpy.linalg.inv) because [Rank defective matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Properties) cannot be inverted, need to supply a square or it can also be a valid `numpy.matrix` instance, the `linalg.inv` method processes `M = np.array([...]) numpy.linalg.inv(M)` incorrectly.