# How to check if a matrix is invertible in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-algebra, inversion

In my Tensorflow graph, I would like to invert a matrix if it is invertible do something with it. If it is not invertible, the, I'd like to do something else.

I could not find any way to check if the matrix is invertible in order to do something like :

```
is_invertible = tf.is_invertible(mat)
tf.cond(is_invertible, f1, f2)
```

Is there such a thing as an `is_invertible` function in Tensorflow ?
I also considered using the fact that Tensorflow raises (not each time though) an `InvalidArgumentError` when I try to invert a non-nvertible matrix, but I couldn't take advantage of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As proposed in [Efficient & pythonic check for singular matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13249108/1782792), you can check the condition number. Unfortunately, this is not currently implemented in TensorFlow as such, but it is not difficult to emulate the basic implementation of [`np.linalg.cond`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.cond.html):

```
import math
import tensorflow as tf

# Based on np.linalg.cond(x, p=None)
def tf_cond(x):
    x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
    s = tf.linalg.svd(x, compute_uv=False)
    r = s[..., 0] / s[..., -1]
    # Replace NaNs in r with infinite unless there were NaNs before
    x_nan = tf.reduce_any(tf.is_nan(x), axis=(-2, -1))
    r_nan = tf.is_nan(r)
    r_inf = tf.fill(tf.shape(r), tf.constant(math.inf, r.dtype))
    tf.where(x_nan, r, tf.where(r_nan, r_inf, r))
    return r

def is_invertible(x, epsilon=1e-6):  # Epsilon may be smaller with tf.float64
    x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
    eps_inv = tf.cast(1 / epsilon, x.dtype)
    x_cond = tf_cond(x)
    return tf.is_finite(x_cond) & (x_cond < eps_inv)

m = [
    # Invertible matrix
    [[1., 2., 3.],
     [6., 5., 4.],
     [7., 7., 8.]],
    # Non-invertible matrix
    [[1., 2., 3.],
     [6., 5., 4.],
     [7., 7., 7.]],
]
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(is_invertible(m)))
    # [ True False]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
if m.shape[0] == m.shape[1]:
    # when m is a square matrix
    try:
        tf.linalg.inv(L)
        print(tf.linalg.inv(L))
        print("invertible")
    except:
        print("not invertible")
else:
    # m is not invertible if it is not even a squared matrix
    print("not invertible")
```

Since when you try to invert a non-invertible matrix with `tf.linalg.inv`, an `InvalidArgumentError` is thrown only when the input, assuming it's 2d is not a square matrix. And when it is not a square matrix, it is outright non-invertible.

Comment: The quesion is pretty old, but if I remember correctly, I had this InvalidArgumentError with square matrices too